# How to make a horizontal StackView to have the first element's width and fill the rest of it

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I'm new with swift and trying to create an input field at the moment. My problem is, that I would like to have a Label as shown in the picture:

[image: mockup input field]

So far, I'm working with StackViews: One vertical one for the input fields, and three horizontal ones to have the Title and the user input. My code so far is as follows:

```
// Initialize outter stackview
    let feedbackOutterSV = UIStackView()
    view.addSubview(feedbackOutterSV)
    feedbackOutterSV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    feedbackOutterSV.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        feedbackOutterSV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tutorialText.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        feedbackOutterSV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        feedbackOutterSV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        feedbackOutterSV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
    ])

    // Initalize inner stackview for title
    let feedbackInnerSVTitle = UIStackView()
    feedbackOutterSV.addArrangedSubview(feedbackInnerSVTitle)
    feedbackInnerSVTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    feedbackInnerSVTitle.axis = .horizontal
    feedbackInnerSVTitle.alignment = .fill
    feedbackInnerSVTitle.distribution = .fillProportionally

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    feedbackInnerSVTitle.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
    titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleLabel.text = "feedback.input.title".localize()
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
    titleLabel.textColor = .gray

    let titleTextView = UITextView()
    feedbackInnerSVTitle.addArrangedSubview(titleTextView)
    titleTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleTextView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
    titleTextView.isScrollEnabled = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 39)
    ])
```

This code gives the expected output for English, however I have to implement it in different languages, so I can't use a constant width.

[image: Screenshot of current view]

Can anyone tell me how to change my code, so I don't need the constant constraint but the width of the Label is adjusted to the length of the word?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `width constraint` on `titleLabel` must be set to `titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width`

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width)
])
```

Also, set the `distribution` of `feedbackInnerSVTitle` as `.fill`

```
feedbackInnerSVTitle.distribution = .fill
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, when I change the code like that it just splits the stack view into half (the Label has 50% of the size and the TextView has 50% of the size) Thanks though!

Comment: Works just like I need it to! Love you, just saved my day :)

Comment: This works... with static text. If you try to change the `titleLabel.text` after the elements have been laid out, the width of `titleLabel` won't change. If that's not a concern, no big deal... just a note of caution.

Answer (score 3):

Couple things...

I assume you want the "title label" to be top-aligned with your textView, so change `.fill` to `.top`:

```
    feedbackInnerSVTitle.alignment = .top // .fill
```

and, don't use `.fillProportionally`

```
    feedbackInnerSVTitle.distribution = .fill // .fillProportionally
```

Now, you'll likely see each element taking 50% of the width, so change the `content hugging` priority for your title label:

```
    titleLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

and, finally, ***don't*** set a width constraint on your title label:

```
//      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
//          titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 39)
//          ])
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0)]` to let it grow depending on the content

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work for me. The word (Title) gets cut and ends with ... Thanks for the input though!